# Merge/Insert Statement ORA-911

Tags: flyway

Below statement generate "ORA-00911: invalid character" issue in ORACLE while migration where as it works fine directly inside AQT/SQL Developer.

```
INSERT INTO ss.CODETBL(FIELDNAME,FIELDVALUE,IDS)
SELECT FIELDNAME,FIELDVALUE,IDS FROM
(
SELECT 'ACCT_TYPE_CD' FIELDNAME, '$' FIELDVALUE,'SAMP' IDS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACCT_TYPE_CD', 'L','SAMP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ACCT_TYPE_CD', 'C','SAMP' FROM DUAL 
)
D
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM SS.CODETBL 
    WHERE D.FIELDNAME = FIELDNAME 
    AND D.FIELDVALUE = FIELDVALUE
    AND D.IDS = IDS
);
```

Comment: In MERGE statement if there is no space between fieldvalue and feildname
then also same error.
SELECT 'ACCT_TYPE_CD'FIELDNAME, '$' FIELDVALUE,'SAMP' IDS FROM DUAL UNION ALL

Comment: Please make sure it is reproducible with the latest Flyway version and file an issue in the issue tracker.

Comment: yes this is reproducible with latest 3.2.1 :)

Comment: Can you please help in this? You can create any merge script or Insert with data selection and mention Field name in first row only and for rest column you can leave as is, technically that is correct but flyway throw error.